# How do I declare an object with array of object inside typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

**I am writing code in typescript with Node.js. And I am using mongoDB as database I am trying to create an schema which accept array of object inside an object. I want output as below:**

_id:objectId(12345)

email:"efg@gmail.com",

teamMate:[

{name:"xyz", email:"xyz@gmail.com",role:true, _id:"36457frh"},

{name:"abc", email:"abc@gmail.com,"role:false,_id:"hgf73"}

]

in model(admin.ts)

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface ITeam {
  email: string,
  name: string,
  role:boolean,
  status:string
}
export interface IAdmin extends Document {
    adminEmail:string;
    teamMate:ITeam[];
}

const AdminSchema = new Schema({
  adminEmail: {type: String, required: true},
  teamMate:{type:Array, required:true}  
});

export default mongoose.model<IAdmin>('Admin', AdminSchema);
```

in app.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import AdminModel, {IAdmin}  from '../models/admin';
const app= express();
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
    dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    pass: process.env.DB_PASS,

  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Database connected successfully!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
app.post('/admin',async function addTeamMate(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
    const adminEmail = req.body.adminEmail;
    const {name, email, role}= req.body.teamMate
    if(!adminEmail) {
        return next(ApiError.badRequest("adminEmail can't be empty"))
    }
    const teamMember:IAdmin= await AdminModel.create({
        adminEmail,
        teamMate:[{
            email,
            name,
            role,
            status:"inActive"
       }],
    })
    res.send(teamMember)
    }catch(e){
        ('Error is ' + e);
        return next(ApiError.internal(e.message));
    }
}

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("starting server at port 3000");
});
```

but getting output as below:
`{ "teamMate": [ { "status": "inActive" } ], "_id": "61e8a6075d4f301ede9bf17d", "adminEmail": "efg@gmail.com", "__v": 0 }`

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have an output; what's the problem with it? What did you expect if to print out?

Comment: actually I am not getting complete output there are two object inside that array and Iam getting only one as response.  I want id for each object inside array too